# Filling missing values based on a specific column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this :

| Day | Type | From | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/09/2021 | car | 170 | Nan |
| 02/09/2021 | car | 140 | Nan |
| 03/09/2021 | none | 120 | 77 |
| 04/09/2021 | car | 15 | 45 |
| 05/09/2021 | car | 34 | Nan |
| 06/09/2021 | car | 36 | 84 |
| 07/09/2021 | none | 23 | 11 |
| 08/09/2021 | car | 36 | Nan |

The logic is
For each row containing a **Type** `none`

- fill the previous Nan rows in column `to` with values from column
  `from`(Only for the beginning of the dataset until the first row with Type `none`)
- fill the following Nan rows in column `to` with values from column `to`

> The values used to fill the missing needs to be taken from the latest
> row containing a Type `none`

Desired output :

| Day | Type | From | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/09/2021 | car | 170 | 120 |
| 02/09/2021 | car | 140 | 120 |
| 03/09/2021 | none | 120 | 77 |
| 04/09/2021 | car | 15 | 45 |
| 05/09/2021 | car | 34 | 77 |
| 06/09/2021 | car | 36 | 84 |
| 07/09/2021 | none | 23 | 11 |
| 08/09/2021 | car | 36 | 11 |

I tried using `ffill` and `bfill` , but I'm not sure how to apply the conditions

Comment: I don't get the logic here, why do the value of the last row in column `to` be at 11 instead of 77 ? You specified "fill the following Nan rows in column `to` with values from column `to`", then all following rows of the 3rd rows should be at 77, isn't it ? Or is this rule only for the next row ?

Comment: last row is 11 because we apply the logic for each row containing a Type `none`
, so if you take a look at the row before it , it contains a Type none , so the new value for the following rows is 11 .. rule is applied if the value of column `to` is Nan only

Comment: @MaikelBastawrous, why does 5/9/2021 has a value of 77 under TO column? shouldn't it be 45?

Comment: Because the value used to fill the missing needs to be taken from the latest row containing a Type `none`. I'll add this to the post for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the ind list, the indexes of the rows are copied, where **'Type' == 'none'**. The dataframe is copied to aaa through a slice on the first element of ind. In ind1 I get the indices of the first rows with **'to' == 'Nan'** and set the values via **loc**.

ind_to its elements are fed into **list comprehensions**, the desired values are set through the **my_finc** function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=0)

ind = df[df['Type'] == 'none'].index
aaa = df[:ind[0]]
ind1 = aaa[aaa['to'] == 'Nan'].index
df.loc[ind1, 'to'] = df.loc[ind[0], 'From']

ind_to = df[df['to'] == 'Nan'].index

def my_finc(x):
    bbb = df.loc[: x, 'Type']
    kkk = bbb[bbb == 'none'].index
    df.loc[x, 'to'] = df.loc[kkk[-1], 'to']


[my_finc(i) for i in ind_to]

print(df)
```

Output

```
          Day  Type  From   to
0  01/09/2021   car   170  120
1  02/09/2021   car   140  120
2  03/09/2021  none   120   77
3  04/09/2021   car    15   45
4  05/09/2021   car    34   77
5  06/09/2021   car    36   84
6  07/09/2021  none    23   11
7  08/09/2021   car    36   11
```